# Can we update public group members when a username in user object or any custom object is updated?

Tags: apex, trigger, wrapper-class

I am having one custom object called clubmember and I wrote one trigger which insert and delete the member to public group object.

I like to know how to write a code to update(i.e if the user change the member of the team) it should get updated in the public group object.

If it possible can you please help me with sample code.

Comment: is group member object another custom object?

Comment: if i assume your issue correctly, it is possible through field updates through workflow. if you want to more logic then go for apex triggers.

Comment: Could you please be a bit clearer here --1) User object is master of ClubMember__c ? 2) Group member is a custom object or are you referring to Public Groups?  3) What is the schema relationship between Group member and Club member?

Comment: @crop1645 1. yes user object is master for clubmemeber__c 2. group member is public groups. 3. whenever clubmember details are updated the public group member detail also get updated.

Comment: OK, this helps but I'm still puzzled - Public Groups are sets of Users. Any data that changes in the User object doesn't affect the Public Group as the Public Group simply points a list of Users. Thus, the only thing I can imagine you would need to do is insert/remove a User from a Public Group if a Club_Member__c is added/deleted (presuming that a Club_member__c can't change its 'club' from A to B). So, please edit your question to be clearer and show your code so far and why it is not working